# Nav bar doesn't sit at the top of the page

Tags: html, css, margin, padding, nav

There is currently a gap between the top of the page and the nav bar. Originally it was fixed and there was no gap. However, when I unfixed it, it added the gap. Margin and padding for both body and html are set at zero.

```css
html{
 font-family: abel;
 background-color: #a4bdd1
}
body{
    overflow-x:hidden;
}
nav {
    text-align: center;
    background-color: #e4e6e5;
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
   left: 0;
   z-index: 9999;
  width: 100%;
  border-bottom: solid #05182e 2px;
}
nav li {
    display: inline-block;
    font-size: 35px;
    padding: 15px;
    font-weight: bold;
    vertical-align: middle;
}

nav a{
 border: solid black 2px ;
 border-radius: 25%;
 padding: 2px;
 background-color: #cccccc;
 color: #1f3b5a;
 text-decoration: none;
 font-size: 30px;
 transition: all 0.5s ease-in-out;
}
nav a:hover{
 font-size: 40px;
 transition: all 0.5s ease-in-out;
}
nav img{
 width: 30%;
 border: none;
 transition: all 0.5s ease-in-out;
}
nav img:hover{
 width: 40%;
 transition: all 0.5s ease-in-out;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
   <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.5.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
 <meta charset="utf-8">
 <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="style2.css">
 <link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Abel' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
 <link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Bitter:700' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
   <link rel="icon" type="image/png" href="favicon-32x32.png" sizes="32x32" />
 <link rel="icon" type="image/png" href="favicon-16x16.png" sizes="16x16" />
 <title>Brampton Thunder Roster</title>
</head>

<body>
 <nav> 
     <ul> 
         <li/><img src="images/logo.png" alt="Canadian Women's Hockey League Logo"></li>
         <li> <a href="index.html" target="_blank">Home</a></li>
         <li> <a href="roster.html" target="_blank">Roster</a></li>
         <li> <a href="schedule.html" target="_blank">Schedule</a></li>
         <li><a href="http://cwhl.ca" target="_blank"><img src="images/cwhllogo.png"></a></li>

     </ul>
 </nav>
```

Comment: No gap for me in the code snippet

Answer (score 1):

It's the top margin of your `<ul>` element causing the problem. Also, your first opening `<li>` tag needs to have the slash removed: `<li/>` is wrong.

```
<nav> 
    <ul> 
        <li/><img src="images/logo.png" alt="Canadian Women's Hockey League Logo"></li>
        <li> <a href="index.html" target="_blank">Home</a></li>
        <li> <a href="roster.html" target="_blank">Roster</a></li>
        <li> <a href="schedule.html" target="_blank">Schedule</a></li>
        <li><a href="http://cwhl.ca" target="_blank"><img src="images/cwhllogo.png"></a></li>

    </ul>
</nav>
```

Fix it by adding:

CSS:

```
ul {
   margin: 0;
}
```

Comment: So, solved? Or, if not, can you give me the url for your actual page?

Comment: also... I want to believe to.